# GLib.idle_add(function) has different policies for different functions

Tags: python, gtk, glib

I have a GTK window. It turns out that if I schedule several redraw calls all at once, without any delay, from a separate thread, using `idle_add(window.queue_draw)`, only one call will execute.

While if I do `idle_add(custom_function)`, every single scheduled call to custom_function will run.

While it's clear that this is done for optimization, I can't see if/where this is mentioned in the documentation [1] and I also wonder if there are other such rules for `idle_add`.

[1] https://developer.gnome.org/pygobject/stable/glib-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It actually isn't `idle_add` that is making that behavior. The docs for [widget-queue-draw-region](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-queue-draw-region), which gets called by `queue-redraw`, state that redrawing only gets done after the main loop is no longer busy.

Comment: _Once the main loop becomes idle (after the current batch of events has been processed, roughly), the window will receive expose events for the **union** of all regions that have been invalidated._ - That explains it, thank you!